# javascript keydown event does not recognize this key combination

Tags: javascript

If I press the keys (a + d + w) or (a + d + s) simultaneously and without releasing any letter, it recognizes both the w and the s in both cases, but when using the combination (w + s + a) o (w + s + d) simultaneously and without releasing any letter, it does not recognize either a or d.
Why does this happen?.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.key == 'd'){
      console.log('d')
  }
  if(e.key == 'a'){
      console.log('a')
  }
  if(e.key == 's'){
      console.log('s')
  }
  if(e.key == 'w'){
      console.log('w')
  }
});
```

Comment: This could be a hardware limitation of your keyboard. Typically, to get a keyboard which can register an arbitrary number of keypresses at once, you need to look at more expensive gaming options. I recommend you test your code using a variety of keyboards!

Comment: I've made your code runnable so that others can test their own keyboards. I personally see the same outcome as you, with my dell laptop.

Comment: thanks for answering, I don't think it's because of the keyboard, since when testing the combinations (a + d + s) or (a + d + w) both the s and the w are detected.

Comment: @Erik rollback (or something like that) is a thing where it only detects n amount of keys where it just ignores other key presses

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6671/258509

Comment: OK thank you very much.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to [Invader Skoodge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1719/invader-skoodge) in [an answer on Gaming Stack Exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6671):

> This is a hardware limitation of your keyboard.  Unfortunately, the
> only solution is that you must purchase a better keyboard that does
> not have this limitation.
>
> To be more specific:
>
> In order to save money, keyboard manufacturers often put many keys on
> the same "circuit" of sorts within the wiring of the keyboard.  This
> prevents multiple keys in the same region of the keyboard from being
> pressed simultaneously.  Sometimes it even prevents more than 2 keys
> at all from across the whole keyboard being pressed at once.  Often
> the <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>alt</kbd> keys are not
> within this limitation, so you can hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and press 2
> other keys at once and it will still work fine.
>
> Even high-end gaming keyboards often have a similar hardware
> limitation, although the cap is much higher so that it is unlikely to
> be reached during the normal course of gaming.

Comment: Please review [our attribution requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and follow this example in the future. Note further that, when it is correctly formatted, there are no issues with submitting it.